# How to crop the following image to extract the part with the digits

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to extract digits from a seven segment based digital meter. I used opencv and ssocr to extract the digits. But there's a problem. The following are meter image:

[image: Meter Image]

Little preprocessing of the image for ssocr:

[image: Cropped meter Image]

Now, I need to crop the image for only the digits to make the ssocr library give results.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did you try template matching? https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html